# How to call first element in associative array

Tags: php

I have this php array `$sfo_array`:

```
Array ( ['sfo_id'] => 747['sfo_title_desc_filename'] => ddd ['sfo_keywords'] => hhh)
```

I need to call first element. I do this with `$sfo_array['sfo_id']` but it doesn't work.

Comment: what does you word "call" mean in this context?

Comment: the structure does not belong to an array? how are you getting that structure var_dump?

Comment: yes i need to call value for the first element (747)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: `$sfo_array = array ('sfo_id'=> 747,'sfo_title_desc_filename' => 'ddd' ,'sfo_keywords' => 'hhh');
echo $sfo_array['sfo_id'];` this will give you 
`///747`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for: `reset()`. Manual: set the internal pointer of an array to its first element.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Answer (score 1):

The array structure which you have mentioned in the Question is wrong,

It should be

```
array('sfo_id' => 747, 'sfo_title_desc_filename' => 'ddd', 'sfo_keywords' => 'hhh')
```

Can you please confirm on that. If so then you will be able to call the element of the Array in the format as below

```
$sfo_array['sfo_id']
```

**Complete Answer**

```
$test=Array ('sfo_id' => 747,'sfo_title_desc_filename' => 'ddd','sfo_keywords' => 'hhh');

echo $test['sfo_id'];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the each function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

var_dump(each($sfo_array));

it will always return the item on the pointer. If you want to reset the pointer to the beginning you can use reset()

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your array definition should be like this:

```
array('sfo_id' => 747, 'sfo_title_desc_filename' => 'ddd', 'sfo_keywords' => 'hhh')
```